# Update column to remove everything before and including a space in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have looked at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321172/a-simpler-way-to-remove-everything-before-and-including-the-first-occurrence-of) [somewhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627409/javascript-strip-everything-before-and-including-a-character) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045373/use-regex-re-sub-to-remove-everything-before-and-including-a-specified-word) [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970791/vba-remove-everything-after-and-including-a-specific-character) for ideas, and did a number of searches like "sqlite ltrim %" but I'm having a surprisingly hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

What I want to do is remove everything before, and including a space in SQLite.

One major issue is that I have to use SQLite from PortableApps, and cannot use MySQL for this.

I tried:

```
UPDATE `temp_Week17` SET `c_name`=ltrim(%,' ');
```

I was thinking I could trim the space from the front easily enough after, but I get a "near '%': syntax error."

Just to see what would happen, I also tried:

```
    UPDATE temp_Week17
    SET c_name = LEFT(c_name, CHARINDEX(' ', c_name) - 1)
    WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', c_name) > 0
```

And that produces a "near '(': syntax error."

Another one I tried was:

```
    UPDATE temp_Week17 SET c_name = ltrim(c_name, ' ');
```

That one runs succesfully but does not change anything.

Updated to add per @scaisEdge:

The column is arranged as so:

```
    |c_name|
    --------
    |John Smith|
    |Abe Lincoln|
    |Taco Cat|
```

And the desired outcome is:

```
    |c_name|
    --------
    |Smith|
    |Lincoln|
    |Cat|
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should concatenate  the two string  (the trimmed and the space)

```
  UPDATE temp_Week17 SET c_name = ltrim(c_name) || ' ' ;
```

or you need  the space before  the trimmed

```
  UPDATE temp_Week17 SET c_name = ' ' || ltrim(c_name)  ;
```

based on the sample provide seems you need substring

```
 UPDATE temp_Week17 SET c_name = ltrim(substr( c_name, instr(c_name, ' '))) ;
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help, @scaisEdge!

The two code snippets say they run successfully, but don't actually change the column at all. Any ideas why that could be happening?

Comment: then try update you answer  and show a proper data sample and the expected result..

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: you want remove the first string and leave only the second?

Comment: More or less. It's all one string including spaces in the column, and some of the last names include spaces. I want to preserve everything that falls after the first occurrence of a space character.

Comment: Thank you. When I entered: 
        
        UPDATE temp_Week17 SET c_name = ltrim(substr(instr(c_name, ' '))) ;

it returned "wrong number of arguments to function substr(): UPDATE temp_Week17 SET c_name = ltrim(substr(instr(c_name, ' '))) ;"

Comment: Actually I got it to do something by adding another value at the end like so: 

UPDATE temp_Week17 SET c_name = ltrim(substr(instr(c_name, ' '),0)) ; (It doesn't matter what 0 is, I tried %, '%', 5, and 10, also)

When I run it that way I don't get the wrong number of arguments error, but it does change the content of c_name into a number.